# Minimal but complete AMD implementation

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, modules

I've got a minimal implementation (under 2k minified) of the [Asynchronous Module Definition](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md) API. So far it handles all of the required stuff (I think; it passes the relevant [unit tests](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-tests), anyway), and none of the optional stuff.

I haven't looked at any other implementations yet, but I'd love to hear feedback from someone who has.

```
(
/** 
    amdlite.js

    @param {Object} global
    @param {undefined=} undefined
*/
function(global, undefined){

    'use strict';

    /** Modules waiting for dependencies to be exported.

        @type {Array.<Module>}
    */
    var pendingModules = [];

    /** New modules since the last script loaded.

        @type {Array.<Module>}
    */
    var newModules = [];

    /** Loaded modules, keyed by id.

        @type {Object.<Module>}
    */
    var cache = { };

    /** Names of modules which are loading/loaded.

        @type {Object.<boolean>}
    */
    var loads = { };

    /** Module definition.

        @name Module

        @constructor

        @param {string?=} id
            Optional string identifying the module.
        @param {Array.<string>?=} dependencies
            Optional array of strings identifying the module's dependencies.
        @param {function(...)?=} factory
            Optional function returning the export value of the module.
        @param {?=} exportValue
            Optional export value for modules without a factory.
        @param {function(Module)?=} generator
            Optional function returning a dynamic export value for the module.
    */
    function Module(id, dependencies, factory, exportValue, generator) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dependencies = dependencies;
        this.factoryFunction = factory;
        this.exports = {};
        this.generator = generator;
        if (!factory) {
            this.exportValue = exportValue || this.exports;
        }
    }

    /** Load dependencies.
    */
    Module.prototype.loadDependencies = function () {
        var dependencies = this.dependencies;
        var id, i, j;

        for (i = dependencies.length; i--;) {
            id = dependencies[i];

            // normalize relative deps
            // TODO: normalize 'dot dot' segments
            if (id.charAt(0) == '.') {
                if (this.id.indexOf('/') >= 0) {
                    id = this.id.replace(/\/[^/]*$/, '/') + id;
                } else {
                    id = '/' + id;
                }
                id = id.replace(/[/]\.[/]/g, '/');
                dependencies[i] = id;
            }

            // load deps that haven't started loading yet
            if (!loads.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                this.loadScript(id);
            }
        }
    };

    /** Check dependencies.

        Checks if all dependencies of a module are ready.

        @param {string=} ignore
            Module name to ignore, for circular reference check.

        @return {boolean} true if all dependencies are ready, else false.
    */
    Module.prototype.checkDependencies = function (ignore) {
        var dependencies = this.dependencies || []; 
        var dep, i;

        for (i = dependencies.length; i--;) {
            dep = getCached(dependencies[i]);
            // if the dependency doesn't exist, it's not ready
            if (!dep) {
                return false;
            }
            // if the dependency already exported something, it's ready
            if (dep.exportValue) {
                continue;
            }
            // if the dependency is only blocked by this module, it's ready
            // (circular reference check, this module)
            if (!ignore && dep.checkDependencies(this.id)) {
                continue;
            }
            // if we're ignoring this dependency, it's ready
            // (circular reference check, dependency of dependency)
            if (ignore && (ignore == dep.id)) {
                continue;
            }
            // else it's not ready
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    /** Get dependency value.

        Gets the value of a cached or builtin dependency module by id.

        @return the dependency value.
    */
    Module.prototype.getDependencyValue = function (id) {
        /** @type {Module} */
        var dep = getCached(id);

        return dep.generator ? dep.generator(this) : dep.exportValue;
    };

    /** Load a script by module id.

        @param {string} id
            Module id.
    */
    Module.prototype.loadScript = function (id) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');

        loads[id] = true;
        script.onload = function() {
            var hasDefinition; // anonymous or matching id
            var module, cached;

            // loading amd modules
            while ((module = newModules.pop())) {
                if ((!module.id) || (module.id == id)) {
                    hasDefinition = true;
                    module.id = id;
                }
                cached = getCached(module.id)
                if (!cached) {
                    cache[module.id] = module;
                }
            }
            // loading alien script
            if (!hasDefinition) {
                module = new Module(id);
                cache[id] = module;
            }
            // set export values for modules that have all dependencies ready
            exportValues();
        };
        script.src = id + '.js';
        document.documentElement.children[0].appendChild(script);
    };

    /** Define a module.

        Wrap Module constructor and fiddle with optional arguments.

        @param {?=} id
            Module id.
        @param {?=} dependencies
            Module dependencies.
        @param {?=} factory
            Module factory.
    */
    function define(id, dependencies, factory) {
        var argc = arguments.length;
        var defaultDeps = ["require", "exports", "module"];
        var module, exportValue;

        if (argc == 1) {
            factory = id;
            dependencies = defaultDeps;
            id = undefined;
        } else if (argc == 2) {
            factory = dependencies;
            if (typeof id == 'string') {
                dependencies = defaultDeps;
            } else {
                dependencies = id;
                id = undefined;
            }
        }
        if (typeof factory != 'function') {
            exportValue = factory;
            factory = undefined;
        }
        module = new Module(id, dependencies, factory, exportValue);
        newModules.push(module);
        pendingModules.push(module);
        setTimeout(function(){ module.loadDependencies(); }, 0);
        exportValues();

        return module;
    }

    /** Get a cached module.

        @param {string} id
            Module id.
    */
    function getCached(id) {
        if (cache.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            return cache[id];
        }
    }

    /** Export module values.

        For each module with all dependencies ready, set the
        export value from the factory or exports object.
    */
    function exportValues() {
        var count = 0;
        var lastCount = 1;
        var i, j, module, factory, args, id, value;

        while (count != lastCount) {
            lastCount = count;
            for (i = pendingModules.length; i--;) {
                module = pendingModules[i];
                if ((!module.exportValue) && module.checkDependencies()) {
                    pendingModules.splice(i, 1);
                    factory = module.factoryFunction;
                    args = [];
                    for (j = module.dependencies.length; j--;) {
                        id = module.dependencies[j];
                        args.unshift(module.getDependencyValue(id));
                    }
                    value = factory.apply(global, args);
                    module.exportValue = value || module.exports;
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /** Built-in require function.

        If callback is present, call define, else return the export value
        of the cached module identified by the first argument.

        https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/require.md

        @param {string|Array.<string>} dependencies
            Module dependencies.
        @param {function()=} callback
            Module factory.

        @return {Module|undefined}
    */
    function require(dependencies, callback) {
        if (dependencies.push && callback) {
            define(dependencies, callback);
        } else if (typeof dependencies == 'string') {
            return getCached(dependencies).exportValue;
        } else {
            throw new Error('malformed require');
        }
    }

    // Built-in dynamic modules

    function dynamic(id, generator) {
        cache[id] = new Module(id, undefined, undefined, undefined, generator);
        loads[id] = true;
    }

    dynamic('require', function (module) {
        function r() {
            return require.apply(global, arguments);
        }
        r.toUrl = function(path) {
            return module.id + '/' + path;
        };
        return r;
    });

    dynamic('exports', function (module) {
        return module.exports;
    });

    dynamic('module', function (module) {
        return module;
    });

    // Exports, closure compiler style

    global['define'] = define;
    global['define']['amd'] = { 'lite': {
        // if we support common config later, do it here.
        'config': function(){}
    } };

}(this));
```

Here is the test config for amdjs-tests, if anyone wants to run them.

```
var config = define.amd.lite.config;
var go = define;
var implemented = { basic: true, anon: true, require: true };
```

- What do you think of the code so far? How can I improve it? Did I do anything stupid or forget something?
- What optional parts of the API should I add? Scraping factories for synchronous `require` calls? Common config? Plugins? Or should I just leave it alone?
- Going in the other direction, it seems that you could have a fully-functional AMD-style module loader without all the CommonJS compatibility stuff (require/exports/module), and it would be about half the size of this. The CJS stuff is required by the AMD API, but ISTM AMD would work fine without it. Any thoughts on that?

By the way, I'm aware that I need to do the `readyState` thing for IE. I'll get to that eventually. If there are any other browser incompatibilities I'd like to hear about them.

Answer (score 3):

This code is good

- JsHint only found 1 unused variable and 1 missing semicolon
- I grokked most of the code after the first read
- Well named variables/functions
- well commented (I am not a big fan of the auto doc comments, but to each their own)
- The exception to commenting is perhaps the `dynamic` part towards the bottom which is incidentally the part I still don't grok too well

For your other questions with regards to API, I have no clue.

Comment: Thanks, I really should start using a linter. The docblocks help closure compiler understand what's going on, so it can warn you when you're breaking your own rules (e.g. if you tell it a parameter is a number and then pass it a string). When closure tells me >90% of my code is typed and isn't throwing any warnings, I feel more confident that it does what I think it does.

Comment: The "dynamic" stuff addresses this part of the spec: `This specification defines three special dependency names that have a distinct resolution. If the value of "require", "exports", or "module" appear in the dependency list, the argument should be resolved to the corresponding free variable as defined by the CommonJS modules specification.` But you're right, I should comment that.

Comment: I learned a new verb ⁺¹

Answer (score 2):

I've found one larger bug in the script. See DANGEROUS tag. This check allows modules to get loaded without all of it's dependencies having export values, it only requires all of it's dependencies to be loaded, not exported.

In my case, in a project with around 4 nesting levels, this causes the scripts to load in an incorrect order, throwing a TypeError during the majority of loads.

A fix for for me was to comment out the rule. Don't however know what kind of other consequences it might have.

```
    Module.prototype.checkDependencies = function (ignore) {
        var dependencies = this.dependencies || [];
        var dep, i;

        for (i = dependencies.length; i--;) {
            dep = getCached(dependencies[i]);
            // if the dependency doesn't exist, it's not ready
            if (!dep) {
                return false;
            }
            // if the dependency already exported something, it's ready
            if (dep.exportValue) {
                continue;
            }
            // if the dependency is only blocked by this module, it's ready
            // (circular reference check, this module)
            // DANGEROUS: this can cause problems with modules with classes
            // which extends subclasses from dependant files. 
            if (!ignore && dep.checkDependencies(this.id)) {
                //continue;
            }
            // if we're ignoring this dependency, it's ready
            // (circular reference check, dependency of dependency)
            if (ignore && (ignore === dep.id)) {
                continue;
            }
            // else it's not ready
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```